# Acrobat PDF Reader add-on for IE not loading for specific URLs

Tags: adobe-reader

I have an application that needs to use Acrobat PDF Reader to display PDFs in the browser. I am using Acrobat Reader X and the dll it uses when it works is AcroPDF.dll. I also have Acrobat Reader X Standard installed along with the regular Reader. When the application is in the Stage environment everything works fine, AcroPDF.dll loads and it all works. However, when the application is in the Production environment the AcroPDF.dll does not load and the application does not work. There is no difference between the two environments except for URLs. Both of the URLs are load balancers that redirect the traffic to the specific servers. The even weirder thing is that Production work and AcroPDF.dll loads when we hit a specific server URL instead of the load balancer URL. Why is it not loading. Why is this happening and better yet, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your load balancer URL is not in the same security zone of Stage URL, refer to below KB
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360

Comment: Are you talking about http and https? Because both environments are https. If not then wouldn't the server URL and load balancer URL have the same security zone?